# What is the .NET attribute to not compile a method in release mode?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, attributes

I know that if I have a block of code I don't want compiled when in release mode I can wrap that code block in:

```
#if DEBUG
   while(true)
{ Console.WriteLine("StackOverflow rules"); }
#endif
```

This will keep this code block from compiling in any mode other than `DEBUG`.

I know there is an attribute that can be placed on an entire method that will do that same, but for the life of me I can't remember what that attribute is. I believe that it’s down the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, but I'm not really sure.

BTW: I'm using .NET 4, but I know this attribute existed in .NET 2 because I have used in in old projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx).

> Indicates to compilers that a method
>   call or attribute should be ignored
>   unless a specified conditional
>   compilation symbol is defined.

You should define it as `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` and make sure that the DEBUG constant is not being defined in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to a ConditionalAttribute you can simply use:

```
#if (!DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the ConditionalAttribute, remember that it cannot be used on functions that return anything other than void or take an out-parameter as argument. A ref-parameter is fine since that variable is instantiated before the method call.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void Success1(string param)

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void Success2(ref string param)

[Conditional("DEBUG")] // out parameter
public void CompileErrorCS0685(out string param)

[Conditional("DEBUG")] // non-void function
public bool CompileErrorCS0578(string param)
```